# powerful command line utility

Tags: command-prompt

Can anyone recommend me a better command-line utility than the built-in 'cmd' window that comes with winXP.

any recommendation would be helpful. Vote for others if you support it so i'll get a better sense what the community thinks.

Thanks

Comment: Poll type questions should be community wiki.

Comment: There's a question just like this over on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/94029/command-line-replacements-for-windows-vista

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One word : [**PowerShell**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx).

It's a great command runner, it's extensible using .NET classes, it's the de facto standard for any admin interface from Microsoft to come.... do you need more reasons? :-)

Comment: Technically two words  ;-)  ...but...yeah, I +1'd you anyway 'cause you are very correct.

Comment: @Jason: you're nit-picking! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The answer really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but have you looked at [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) (marked as beta but stable in practice).

It's just a console replacement, not a new Unix like shell like Bash under [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com). And actually, I'm running Cywgin inside Console.